# Can you take both whey protein and mass gainer at the same time?

Tags: nutrition, diet, proteins

I heard from one of my friend once that told me that when I'm consuming whey protein, I shouldn't also consume mass gainer. Can consuming these two together be harmful? If so, how long should I wait after consuming one to have the other?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? What reason did your friend evoke?

Answer (score 4):

You're essentially asking if you can eat food and then eat more food.  Whey protein and mass gainer at the most basic level are: carbs, proteins, and fat.  In the case of mass gainer, it usually has large amount of both carbs and protein.  So, yes, you can consume them at the SAME TIME, just as you can consume 2 or 10 cheeseburgers at the same time.  The underlying question I believe you intended to ask was, "What is the value/repercussions in doing so?"  And, the not so simple answer is, it *depends*

It depends on your target Calorie consumption.  Are you aiming to intake 2000 calories or 5000?  How many calories are you burning during your regular activities and during your athletic activities?  If you're looking for optimal muscle protein synthesis, you would be more interested in BCAAs - specifically [Leuceine](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21775557).

I can tell by your question that you're a novice with regards to nutrition, and a single forum post will not suffice.  Please google "Jordan Feigenbaum".  He has written extensively on nutrition in the setting of weightlifting.  As always, read everything with a critical eye.  Best of luck.

Comment: This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)